# Cannot get response when connecting to OpenConnect

Tags: vpn, openconnect

I have connected successfully to my VPN using openconnect. OpenConnect VPN provides me an IP suppose the IP is 9.9.9.9.By using VPN I can request a specific API and get the response back. But the problem is on those API  are sending me a callback response to my pc via an API whose URL is, for example, http://9.9.9.9:7899/something. Now the problem is I don't get any callback response those API which is accessible only through VPN. I am using cisco anyconnect VPN protocol